# Mac File Path for ImageIcon

Tags: java, file, path, imageicon

I want to create a new ImageIcon (Using a Mac) and I tried this:

```
public void loadPics() {
    ImageIcon bg = new ImageIcon("Users/USERNAME/Documents/Photos/Randombg.png").getImage();
    ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon("Users/USERNAME/Documents/Photos/Randomrandom.png").getImage();
}
```

I have other code for drawing up the images and I know that will work fine, it's just that the path is incorrect.

Comment: Are these images supplied by you or the user?  If by you, access them as an [tag:embedded-resource] by `URL`.  If the user, offer them a [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following if you are using full path:

```
/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Photos/Randombg.png
```

OTOH:

```
Users/USERNAME/Documents/Photos/Randombg.png
```

Users is a sub-folder of the folder where the execution started.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the users home directory, it's better to use the `user.home` `System` property

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```